# C# Winforms - How to change the 0,0 index in a DataGridView from top-left to bottom-left?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have been scratching my head over this one the last couple of days and cant seem to find or figure out the answer.

I have a `DataGridView` with `TextBoxCell`s in it, the user can set the size of the grid. The 0,0 start index is top-left and I want it to start counting the cells bottom-left.

I know there is a property to change the `DataGrid` to right-to-left, any way to also change it to bottom-to-top?

Is there any way to achieve this?
Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: have you share any sample

Comment: No, you can't change the top-to-bottom indexing, but you can expose a different indexing where the vertical index is the rowCount - indexValue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right-to-left change is to accommodate languages like Hebrew or Arabic that are written from right to left. It's not there for you to have indexing start in a different corner (it probably also affects text rendering in the control, so there are side-effects you probably don't want).

The usual way to solve this is to have a set of methods that convert your special indices to those used in the control and vice-versa. They're trivial to write. Just make sure that every time you access indices you'll use your methods instead of using the DataGrid's own ones.

Comment: I'll give it a try or else will leave it as is. thanks.